# I want to shutdown my computer 12:30 am,but shutdown does nothing

Tags: 12.10

Cronjob of shutdown using vi:

```
30 00 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

I have tried everything.

Comment: Have you restarted cron? `/etc/init.d/cron restart`

Comment: @user179723 have you tried 30 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now

Comment: Don't forget that you need root access (through `sudo`) to shutdown the computer.

Comment: I know I need root access,but how when starting a shutdown command in vi.

Comment: I use start cron #start: Unknown job: cron

Comment: You do not start anything in `vi`. `vi` is an editor. You are editing a file that the `cron` program will read and schedule the program execution for later.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you add the cronjob as root user? To check whether you have added it as root user type (in terminal): `crontab -u root -l`
2. If you have added it correctly and yet the system doesn't shutdown, then try it manually in terminal first (as root user): `shutdown -h now`
3. If step 2 fails to shutdown with command not found, type this in terminal: `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin`

   (or) use a editor like nano to open .bashrc and add the `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` manually as follows: `sudo nano /root/.bashrc`. (If you have not installed nano, install it using `sudo apt-get install nano`)

Now, try shutdown command as root user and it should work. Once this works, cronjob will also work.

Comment: must be privileged to use -u

Comment: step 2 shutdown -h now as sudo worked,but I will try step 3 eventhough I don't know nano so well,I'm new to Ubuntu

Comment: export PATH=$PATH:/sbin worked in terminal,but sorry to say I don't know how to open my .bashrc,do you mean I can put export PATH=$PATH:/sbin into vi using crontab -e,sorry for my grammar

Comment: I have really tried everything even saving a cron job which then tells me system shutdown will occur in XXX min,to no avail,I'm tired and I dont know what I'm missing

Comment: does: "sudo crontab -l" show you your line with the shutdown command?

Comment: nano is an editor. Install it using sudo apt-get install nano in terminal. Then issue the command as follows: sudo nano /root/.bashrc (This will open the .bashrc file for root user). Then add "export PATH=$PATH:/sbin" without quotes. Then, press ctrl+x to save and quit. Now, type source /root/.bashrc so that the current terminal recognizes the addition to PATH environmental variable. Now, try shutdown -h now and it should work. So will the cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

1) Prepare a file with the crontab entry for root:

```
echo "30 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -h now" > myrootcron.sh
```

(that means half past midnight).

2) Install the file as crontab entry for the root user:

```
sudo crontab -u root myrootcron.sh
```

3) Check it is installed:

```
sudo crontab -u root -l
```

That should do it. More information using `man cron` and `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: Two things I prepared a file for 5:30 am to see if it works,tell me crontab -r would remove it and then how can I add a message that lets me stay logged on only if I decide I don't want the shutdown to go through.Thanks in advance

Comment: a) can't understand your comment. I know that sometime is difficult to express themselves in a language which is not our mother language, as my case, but please try to be more correct. b) this site is for asking question, not for having the work done. Please study `man cron` and `man 5 crontab`, try some solution, and if you have problems again write another question.